# Which 2016 GOP primary candidates will be on the primary ballot in California?

Tags: united-states, primaries

Now that all candidates except Trump have dropped out and/or suspended their campaigns, he is the [presumptive GOP nominee](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10790/is-donald-trump-officially-the-republican-nominee).  That said, there are still states that haven't voted yet, of which California is the largest.

**Which candidates will still be on California's GOP primary ballot?**  Are candidates removed simply by suspending their campaign, or do they need to file paperwork, or is it just too late to make changes?  And are any of the original 17 who dropped out much earlier still on there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I voted in Maryland, all the candidates were on the ballot because the ballot contains the list of those who had filed and certified their candidacy, **even though they had withdrawn from the race** after the filings had been certified. Similarly, the California [Official Certified List of Candidates](http://elections.cdn.sos.ca.gov//statewide-elections/2016-primary/june-2016-presidential-candidates.pdf) was certified as of April 1, 2016 and still had the entire list of candidates who were running as of that date for both parties.

It appears that once the certified list is filed, the ballot cannot be modified. Currently, Ben Carson, Ted Cruz, Jim Gilmore, John Kasich, and Donald Trump are still listed for the Republicans.